# Deterministic (not subjective) search engine

Tags: search

Trying to find a search engine that actually just searches for what I type, and respects the modifying operators I use.  Need to do a lot of exact searches, but Google gives shopping and does not respect search terms.

Comment: What modifying operators & search terms?

Comment: Do you want to (A) build your own corpus, and install your own customized text-mining software, and build+host your own local search-index or (B) find a search engine built by others, that tracks the entire internet, and has certain search operators?

Comment: What.  I'm just trying to find a search service that looks for only what I type in, like Google and Yahoo and most search engines used to be, rather than try to predict what I didn't want, and give me that.

Comment: I share this desire. Sometimes I am trying to find something very specific, and the most salient feature I can think of is that the page I want will contain some exact literal text that can be found with ctrl-F, and/or will definitely not contain some other text. Modern search engines simply refuse to take such criteria seriously.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do exact searches, almost all search engines will do so if you put your search terms within double quotes, e.g. `"search engine"`. They become more deterministic (or at least less reliant on personal data) if you use a private browser window, and a VPN may help too.

Otherwise, I'd recommend [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/):

> because there is no search history on DuckDuckGo, you escape the filter bubble of manipulated results.

A search engine cannot be completely deterministic: web pages are continually indexed, so if a new page is created (or linked to more often), which fits your query better than older results, search results *will* change.

Comment: This is wrong.  You will notice that even in quotes these days, Google based searches often land up ignoring what is in the quote, adding an AI suggested match or AI ignoring it's existence.  You will find it even giving options to include the quoted text.  I was using Google when the AI took over, and it was the most horrible experience.  If nobody is going give a credible answer (and just make irrelevant dishonest edits trying to make out conservative sentence forms are typos) then this service is corrupted.

Comment: Even with DuckDuckGo in an incognito window, I have found that it is **common** to search for `foo "bar"`, examine the first page of results, and find that I cannot ctrl-F `bar` in most of them. Similarly, `foo -bar` will show me lots of results with `bar`, even in the page title. (Not for the same values of `foo` and `bar`, of course.) Even the help page says that it will show *less* bar in the results, not exclude it. I get that the Internet isn't static, but it should be trivial to get search results that are more literal than what current search engines do.